# NET Core 2.0 site Prerendering timed out after 30000ms

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I'm facing an issue when deploying a NETCORE 2.0 app to IIS.

Prerendering timed out after 30000ms because the boot function 'ClientApp/dist/main-server' returned a promise that did not resolve or reject.[image]